# What is the difference between curly braces and curly brackets?

Tags: difference, terminology

I'm really confused about it, sometimes I read something and it refers to `{}` as curly braces  and sometimes to curly brackets, what is the difference between those two terms? Are they referring to the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Braces**: (also known as curly brackets, or curly braces)
>
> [image]

Yes, they are the same thing.

And, actually, there are many names for it. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket),

> `{ }` — braces (UK and US), flower brackets (India), French brackets, curly brackets, definite brackets, swirly brackets, curly braces, birdie brackets, Scottish brackets, squirrelly brackets, gullwings, seagulls, squiggly brackets, Tuborg brackets (DK), accolades (NL), pointy brackets, or fancy brackets

Comment: I had an elementary school teacher who referred to them (informally) as _Alfred Hitchcocks_, owing to their resemblance to the [famed director's profile](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1219&bih=827&q=hitchcock+silhouette).

Comment: They're the same thing. As a UK speaker my feeling is that most Brits would refer to "brackets" whilst "braces" is more of a US usage.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can answer but not comment on the answer, let me rephrase this as a new answer:

See the [above mentioned Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket).

A brace is a curly bracket, but not all brackets are braces.
Think of bracket as the general term for the opening and closing things, and brace (or curly bracket) as the special characters {}

(), [] and <> are also brackets, but no braces.

- () are parentheses or round brackets
- [] are brackets or square brackets
- <> are chevrons or angle brackets